# c++ Using multiple lambdas/binds to reference the same function/functionality

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stdbind

I am writing some tests for a class. I have multiple tests and each one creates its own `MyObj`. However, `MyObj` takes in a `std::function<bool<T>>`, and I don't want to create a lambda function with the same functionality every time I create `MyObj`. So instead of having this:

```
TEST1()
{
  MyObj<double> myobj([&](double time) -> bool 
      {
        time = myobj.doSomething();
        // ... more functionality
      });
}


TEST2()
{
  MyObj<double> myobj([&](double time) -> bool 
      {
        time = myobj.doSomething();
        // ... more functionality
      });
}

...
```

Rather I want to have the function defined once and reference it every time I have to create a new `MyObj`:

```
bool myFunc(double time)
{
  time myobj.doSomething();
  // ... more functionality
}

TEST1()
{
  MyObj<double> myobj([&myFunc]()); // Something like this
}

TEST2()
{
  MyObj<double> myobj(std::bind(&myFunc, myobj, std::placeholders::_1));  // Or something like this
}
```

So some things to note:

- Class `MyObj`, all copy/reference constructors have been deleted.
- Theres more functionality associated with myFunc which is why I don't want to repeat every time since there are numerous test cases.
- I need a reference to the `MyObj` created in the actual function (myFunc).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `bool myFunc(double time)` should be `bool myFunc(MyObj<double>& myobj, double time)`, then you can use second method.

Comment: Your test framework may also support feature, so you might move `myobj` there.

Comment: @Jarod42 actually as I mentioned, copy/reference constructors are deleted so thats why second method does not work. But your answer below worked perfectly thanks.

Comment: You also have to use `std::ref(myobj)` for the binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create regular functor:

```
struct Functor
{
    MyObj<double>& myobj;

    explicit Functor(MyObj<double>& myobj) : myobj(myobj) {};

    auto operator ()(double time) const -> bool 
    {
        time = myobj.doSomething();
        // ... more functionality
    }
};
```

With usage:

```
TEST1()
{
    MyObj<double> myobj(Functor(myobj));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you added some detail on whats going on in the Functor and how this works for the newer c++ folks and maybe some unfamiliar with these features. Just a thought.